# Geopy using the Google Maps v3 API: How to plot an optimal TSP route on a map

Tags: geopy

I kindly need help with plotting optimal routes from my optimization model on say google map using the 'geopy' and google map v3 api. The image below illustrates an example of the optimal routes obtained from my model with the corresponding zip codes of cities.

[image]
My objectives are as follow:

1. plot each of the routes for each of the salesmen on say a google map showing the routes using the corresponding zip codes. For example, salesman1 travels from city1(zip code 13901) -> city3(zip code 13903) -> city4(zip code 13905) and then ending back at city1(zip code 13902). Similar for salesman2 and salesman3
2. the plot from point 1 must follow the road that leads to the shortest path between the points, lastly
3. I would like to show the direction of the optimal path if at all possible.

I know how to plot zip code information using the google maps using the 'My Maps', but this does not address what I am trying to accomplish here as described above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Routing is not in the scope of geopy, so you'll have to look somewhere else. You may find some references here: https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/318

Comment: Looking up the OSMnx module, it's great!